# RTSP Stream Bad Request in Xcode

Tags: xcode, stream, rtsp, bad-request

We have a DVR analog camera Truvision.

DVR is able to stream their own program , port:8000.

We want to get the broadcast over RTSP 554 ports. What we can not do if we try :(

We tested the modem and port 554 open.

We have made steps in the user name and password.

**rtsp://admin:pass@78.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/1**

or

**rtsp://admin:pass@78.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=8&subtype=00**

or

**rtsp://admin:pass@78.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/11**

but we have always error on this Xcode:

**line='RTSP/1.0 400 Bad Request'**

How can we solve this problem ?

How Do We Get the RTSP stream broadcast Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late,but try using

**rtsp://ipaddress:port/user=[*yourusername*]&password=[*yourpassword*]&channel=1&stream=0.sdp**

Comment: rtsp://admin:MyPass@78.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/1
         
rtsp://admin:MyPass@78.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=8&subtype=00
         
rtsp://admin:MyPass@78.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/11

Comment: this links not working TruVision DVR open modem 554 port and test is ok but stream 404 or 401 :/ thank you

Comment: @Jealian Are you using an external ip?If so,then it needs to be port forwarded.The method I gave you definitely works for internal IP,but external IP that's a different story due to many reasons  (firewall,NAT,etc)                  

P.S,internal IP only works if your DVR and your app is connect on the same wifi

Comment: Hi Fay Zan. I added 554 ports in modem and test. 554 port is open. But DVR not working 554 rstp stream :(   :  |    Model Truvision

Comment: well 554 is the default rtsp and only works for internal IP ex: 192.168.xxx.xxx,you should open your DVR setting and look up at the network setting.It should tell you what port is used on media,HTTP,and mobile.port forward those numbers and try using the mediaport on you apps and use public IP ex rtsp://publicip:mobileport/user=[user]&password=[password]&channel=1&stream=0.sdp

If it still doesn't work then I can no longer help you cuz after that the problem has too much of a possibility such as NAT,your ISP is blocking UDP,android version and etc